# Could not find type...Platform issues in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I just jumped back into a project that previously had no issues. We just upgraded to visual studio 2012. This morning I open my project to work on my code. I am getting designer issues all over the place.

"If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built using settings for your current platform or Any CPU"

It all seems to be coming from this platform issue. I have had zero issues in the past. I cannot find any information on how to fix this. I even go to open the designer on a file that previously worked (pre VS2012 install) and that fails.

So I went back to VS2010...without changing anything and attempted to open the same designer on the same file that previously worked and I also get an app crash.

Did somehow my visual studio 2012 install cause all of this?

Comment: When you opened the project did you tell it to convert it to 2012? If you don't back it up it won't open in 2010 any longer.

Comment: I didn't see anything asking me about converting. Just opened up. I can still open the solution in 2010 also. My one project even still looks like the .sln file has the 2010 icon for it. This is just all very confusing.

Comment: Did you try to build it?

Comment: yes, did you do what it asked and built the project?

Comment: I went through many steps. I built the project, didn't help. Clean > rebuild, didn't help. Removed all references, add back in, clean > rebuild, didn't help. Verified all projects are set to x64 (as they should and were) didn't help. I am stuck.

Comment: You may have a open .dll somewhere, try a clean reboot and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are choosing the right CPU architecture for your designer. If it is ARM then you might see that message. You can check your CPU settings for your project like this:

[image: CPU Settings]

Comment: One issue though, I don't have the x64 option on all of my projects platforms. Only some of them have it and when I try to assign x64 or create a new one it says i can't

Comment: @Tom I just gave that value as an example, you can choose Any CPU. Make sure that it is not ARM.